# Globally show numbers to be localized formatted

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, format

It's nice to change one place that reflects everywhere in Angular app it gives you a good feeling on having control on your app.
I have to change format of numbers to be in DE format for everywhere in an Angular13 app,
Say I have this in the TS file:
`const number = 42342.42;`
then in the HTML template file:
instead of having `{{number}}` I change it to `{{number.toLocaleString('de')}}`
but we have "tons" of this line in the whole app, is there a way to change the template rendering of numbers to be by default formatted with `.toLocaleString('de')` or with any other way of formatting so there's no need to do hundreds of lines of changes in Angular app?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to a global solution for your problem would be creating a prototype format for number. But you'd still have to call a method.

```js
Number.prototype.format = function() {
    return this.valueOf().toLocaleString('de')
}

const number = 42342.42;

console.log(number.format())
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but in this case we will still need to do tons of changes on same lines as before! we need to add/do one change somewhere to change the way of showing `{{number}}` everywhere in Angular.

Comment: Modifying `Number.prototype` is a really, really, super bad idea. See [Why is extending the DOM/built-in object prototypes a bad idea?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/104320/why-is-extending-the-dom-built-in-object-prototypes-a-bad-idea). A notable case of when modifying the prototype of builtins went wrong was [SmooshGate](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/smooshgate/).